# Outer scope this lost in js then function

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I am new to React Native and ES6. I can access outer scope 'this' in this code:

```
my_function()
{
    this.setState = {};//outer scope this

    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(this); //this shows the correct outer scope this
        return response.json()})
      .then(...);

}
```

But if I write this arrow function out as:

```
 return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
        .then(function(response){
           console.log(this); //this becomes some 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope' when I am debugging?
           return response.json();
        }).then(...)
```

I don't understand why this two function is not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the arrow functions are automatically bound.

If you want to have the same result you should write:

```
return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then(function(response){
       console.log(this); //this becomes some 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope' when I am debugging?
       return response.json();
    }.bind(this)).then(...)
```

I have added ".bind(this)" after the closing "}" of the function.